# Can I move an animated line from right to left?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm animating line with css3 from width:0 to width:100%. At the moment is moving from left to right, but I want to make it to start from right to left. Is this posible at all with keyframes?

here is my code

```css
 .content {
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   position: relative;
   background: #333;
 }
 .content .line {
   height: 2px;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   -webkit-animation: dude .75s 1 forwards;
   -moz-animation: dude .75s 1 forwards;
   -o-animation: dude .75s 1 forwards;
   animation: dude .75s 1 forwards;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes dude {
   0% {
     width: 0;
   }
   100% {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes dude {
   0% {
     width: 0;
   }
   100% {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
 @-o-keyframes dude {
   0% {
     width: 0;
   }
   100% {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
 @keyframes dude {
   0% {
     width: 0;
   }
   100% {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the only prefix you even [need to consider for CSS animations is `-webkit-`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)... and I wouldn't even bother with that anymore :) `-moz-` and all the other prefixes are just bloat here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6qax4tep/)

add

```
.content .line {
   right: 0;
}
```

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
}
.content .line {
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dude .75s 1 forwards;
  animation: dude .75s 1 forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dude {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes dude {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the only prefix you even [need to consider for CSS animations is `-webkit-`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)... and I wouldn't even bother with that anymore :) `-moz-` and all the other prefixes are just bloat here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to animate "left" property instead of width as your element already has position set to absolute.

```
@keyframes dude {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/owv63t8f/)

Comment: will this keep the drawing effect as this is what I'm going for here ?

Answer (score 0):

change `animation-direction` to `reverse`

```
animation: dude .75s 1 reverse;
```